# Issues with plotting multivariable line graph in r using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted data table with the columns 'date'/'variable'/'value'.

As far as I can tell, the number of rows for all match up perfectly, however when trying to plot them together using:

```
ggplot(data = subset(data_long, !is.na(value)),
       aes(x=date, y=value, group = variable)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
  geom_line()
```

This returns:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3542
```

I have a few ideas as to why this might be happening. Some of the values in the third column are n/a (though I have now removed these rows with the !is.na expression), and the date is in the format Year-month-day time (e.g. '2017-06-29 00:00:00.0'). However I have no idea whether either of these are the cause, and I am stuck for ideas as to how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

how I generated my data table from the raw data using the reshape package

```
pivot = cast(table, workingdate ~ trader, value = variable1)
cumulative = cumsum(pivot[,-1]) #taking the cumulative sum of all columns except the date
data = data.frame(pivot$workingdate,cumulative) 

data_long <- melt(data, id="pivot.workingdate")  # convert to long format
data_long$pivot.workingdate = as.Date(data_long$pivot.workingdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

And the output from `dput(head(data_long))` (variable names replaced):

```
structure(list(pivot.workingdate = structure(c(17171, 17172, 
17175, 17176, 17177, 17178), class = "Date"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "J", 
"K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", 
"T", "U", "V", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(-0.324163711670048, 0.133077732043205, 0.520368058673496, 
    0.513543560907851, 0.36852295463088, 0.515249684437591)), .Names = c("pivot.workingdate", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = subset(data_long, !is.na(value)),
       aes(x=pivot.workingdate, y=value, group = variable)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this changed anything... Still gives the exact same error.

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the data so that we can reproduce the error? PS But the additional `+` does need to be included.

Comment: Would a simple copy paste from the RStudio table viewer suffice?

Comment: @alex1stef2 Please, use `dput(head(data))`. The printed version doesn't show the data types which is importnat for the date-time column.

Comment: Hopefully edited with what you asked for + more information on how I created my table

Comment: Based on your edits, should `aes(x=date...` read `aes(x=pivot.workingdate...`? I've updated my answer, which now works with the data you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sort of mortified that I spent so long struggling and didn't notice that one mistake... The error makes sense as well!

Comment: No problem! Glad that it works. Note also that the argument for `scale_x_date` is now `date_labels`.